# listView onclick activity

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I have a listView with some data coming from a server.I want to do an activity every time i press one of the list items.any idea please?

```
public void Status1() {
        setContentView(R.layout.status);
        update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
        refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refresh);

        update.setOnClickListener(update_btn);
        refresh.setOnClickListener(refresh_btn);

        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);

        // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in
        // list.

        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr));

         lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                  // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
              });

        final EditText username2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username1);
        //String a = username1.getText().toString();

        //username2.setText(a);
        username2.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    // Perform action on key press
                    // Editable a=findViewById(R.id.username).getText();
                    // username2.setText(a);

                    Toast.makeText(yassou.this, username2.getText(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

i have tried this:EDIT1

```
 lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {



                     startActivity(new Intent("com.example.HelloGoogleMaps2"));
                }
              });
```

and this:EDIT2

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                  // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), HelloGoogleMaps2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


                }
              });
```

but noone method is working...please help!!

Comment: ok,this code i added is working.This returns me a toast.What i have to add in order to open a new activity?

Comment: did you declare the HelloGoogleMaps2 in your manifest file? what messages returns the logcat?

Comment: yes,i had forgotten to declare the new class!unbelievable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach an intent and a bundle as part of the adapter for the listview. This will pass an appropriate bundle to the activity being launched when user clicks on the list item.